# Why does getInitialProps runs on redirect but not on page refresh? (NextJS)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

a quick NextJS Question -> Why does getInitialProps is running when a page is being redirected to (using Router.push \ Router.replace for example), but isn't running on a page refresh? What's the rational behind this?

Thanks!

- I'm using a bit old NextJS version -> 6.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For the initial page load, getInitialProps will execute on the server
>   only. getInitialProps will only be executed on the client when
>   navigating to a different route via the next/link component or by
>   using next/router.

This means it'll be invoked in Initial Page Load -Refreshes Apply- where it get's executed in the server side, not the client side. As [from](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)